# Are there any examples of finding ancestor elements in an adjacency list db?

Tags: sql, sqlite, recursion, hierarchy

I have a DB in SQLite3 and I'm trying to figure out a recurrent query to get all ancestor elements from a many-to-many hierarchy.  I can find lots of examples of traveling down the hierarchy, but no examples of going up.  I don't need the whole path, just the top level element.

The table is organized like this:
parentID | name | childID | level

Thanks!

Comment: Rotate the tree by 180°, then go down.

Comment: You're right Yoda, thanks!
I reversed the order of the query elements and that did it.

Comment: Then please write an answer to show the solution.